# Compiling VMime in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vmime

EDIT:

I'm trying to compile Vmime from the Vc++ project file they supported in the zip and i get this : http://pastebin.com/RXpBQ2Wa

I searched on google but no one had this kind of error : /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably doesn't work with path names with spaces in them, since the `copy` in the error log doesn't seem to have quotes around its arguments.